# How can I format a number like this xxxx-xx-xxxx

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, antd

I'm using antd form item and I tried the below pattern but it's not working.

```
 rules: [{
     pattern: new RegExp("^d{4}-d{2}-d{4}$"),
     message: "Please check  format"
 }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the digits as `\d` and not just `d`. Also, you can use a literal expression like this:

```
pattern: /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/
```

Or define it as a string passed to the [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor but you will have to escape the backslashes, leading to `\\d` instead of `\d`:

```
pattern: new RegExp('^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}$')
```

You can use a tool like [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) to help build and validate your regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using your `RegEx` like this:

```
^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$
```